# Android - Storing 3d models or creating them

Tags: java, android, performance, memory-management, 3d

Which is best for Android?

I have 30 3D models but there is only ever one drawn on the screen at any time.

Do I:

- create the model and destroy the previous model every time the displayed one changes.

or

- create all 30, store them and just reference them when I want to draw them.

Note that when one model is removed another model appears and the transition must be smooth.

In what context would one be better than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried loading all of them at once? Start with that, and if it doesn't work, *then* look at memory management. You should be able to keep at least three or four models in memory on an older device. If you do have issues with ram, try to predict which models are going to be used next, and pre-load them in.

Keeping them all loaded is normally preferable, because it means your app will appear fluid and responsive.